# Download full data export from LastFm for recommender system

Tags: api, spotify, recommendation-engine, last.fm

I am looking to build a recommender system and serching for data along with number of listeners and other attributes. I found last.fm provides this information but how do get all the available track data model training? Or should I download the data from other sources and use the 'track.search' API for all of them?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [ListenBrainz](https://listenbrainz.readthedocs.io/en/production/dev/listenbrainz-dumps/), which collects and regularly publishes data dumps of last.fm's scrobbles as open data.